# Unable to use Mongoid::GridFs put to upload files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, gridfs

I'm just trying to use the mongoid-grid_fs gem in order to upload images and files to MongoDB.

The controller code in question currently looks like this:

```
grid_fs = Mongoid::GridFs
encFile = File.open(attFile)

File.open(encFile, 'wb') do |f|
  f.write(encData)
end

grid_file = grid_fs.put(encFile.path)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass
/GEMS/bundler/gems/mongoid-grid_fs-2f0e12e85a24/lib/mongoid/grid_fs.rb:150:in `put'
(eval):2:in `put'
/x/app/controllers/runtime/attachments_api_controller.rb:126:in `upload'
```

FYI line 126 in attachments_api_controller is the grid_fs.put line.

I'm not sure what the issue is.
I have also declared `require 'mongoid/grid_fs'`

I have put bindings around the issue, I can confirm that encFile.path is correct and it contains valid data.

EDIT 1: I've tried different combinations of trying to put the file like
`grid_fs.put(encFile)` - `grid_fs.put(File.open(encFile.path))` - `grid_fs.put(File.read(encFile.path))` but all of these still return the same error.

Comment: This is not correct usage of the library.

Comment: @D.SM Are we talking about the same library? https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid-grid_fs
It looks exactly how you're meant to use the library.
Could you please elaborate on your comment?

Comment: Your example uses variables that are not defined, making it difficult to understand what you are trying to do, but even so put takes an IO object and not a path.

Comment: You may also consider using the driver directly. https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-gridfs/

Comment: How would you make it take an IO object? I've tried passing it as File.open and File.read but neither of these work.

Comment: File.open returns an IO object. Remove the destroy call on line 150 to see what the original error is.

Comment: As stated in the edit, passing File.open(encFile.path) does not work.
You want me to remove that destroy call in the gem itself? I can give it a go..

Comment: It works for me which means either your patches to the library break it since you are apparently not using a released version, or you have an environmental problem like you are in a fips environment which prohibits md5.

Comment: I haven't made any patches to the library, md5 hashes are working in other places.